# Mouseover is only firing the first time, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is fairly simple but I've been having a stab for too long so would really appreciate some help. Any ideas **why this only works on the first hover**?

```
var divwidth = $('#donatebutton').width();
var divheight = $('#donatebutton').height();

var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divwidth)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divheight)).toFixed();

$('#donatebutton').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px'
    }).appendTo( 'body' );

});
```

Comment: it would be great if you provided a jsfiddle

Comment: `posx` and `posy` don't change between hovers... so what do you expect to happen? You are always setting the same values for `left` and `top`. The handler is executed, but it won't any visual effect. Add a `console.log` statement and see for yourself.

Comment: try .on('mouseover');

Comment: @Ganesh: That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: (facepalm) thanks a million Felix. How dumb, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this code:

```
var divwidth = $('#donatebutton').width();
var divheight = $('#donatebutton').height();

var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divwidth)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divheight)).toFixed();

$('#donatebutton').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px'
    }).appendTo( 'body' );

});
```

to this code

```
var divwidth = $('#donatebutton').width();
var divheight = $('#donatebutton').height();

$('#donatebutton').mouseover(function(){
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divwidth)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divheight)).toFixed();
    $(this).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px'
    }).appendTo( 'body' );

});
```

this will change the random value on the mouseover

Comment: This doesn't really make a difference, unless something else changes the `document` dimensions in the meantime.

Comment: Mmh I must have missed that :D nvm then ;)